# Rest API w/ JsonServer in Ubuntu - Connection Refused

Tags: networking, ubuntu, api, json

I was requested to create a Web Server with an API in it to test firewall rule we are planning to implement soon. I am quite new with all this network stuff, so I'm a bit lost on it.

I need to call this API from another machine. The JsonServer is using my port 3000, when I request my API through Postman, using https://localhost:3000/posts, my JSON file is returned normally, however when I change the localhost, to my IP, my connection is being refused. I decided to install a WebServer, to test it and I could access the default Apache page from my others machines. I opened the port 3000 on my server, but I couldn't. The WebServer is working with my IP as well. It seems to be something with my port 3000, and I a not sure about how to fix that.

I executed the command:

```
sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep 3000
```

And this was my output

```
node      29472           user 22u  IPv4 254348      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:3000 (LISTEN)
```

Any ideas how can I access my API from another machine?

Comment: Are you using the IP of the computer in the local network, which might be something like `192.168.x.x`?

Comment: When I type 'ip a', there is a IPv4, this is the one Im using, which is 10.104.x.x, couldnt find any 192.168.x.x

Comment: `10.x.x.x` is a local network IP, although `10.104.x.x` is uncommon. Can you telnet to port 3000?